# Azure app service - how to make Always On work for specific application?

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

We have an Azure app service, in which several web apps are deployed:

```
/ - root
/app1 - first application
/app2 - second application
...
```

At root we have simple web site, and apps are ASP.NET Web API services.
app1 is running some background tasks so we need it to be always active. To achieve this, we set Always On option in app service settings. We expect, that both root web site and all applications will be always loaded, but behaviour is different: **it seems that applications are not staying alive**.

Our background jobs (powered by Hangfire) are not triggering at schedule, but if any user hit the app with any request, app awakens and starts to process jobs.

So the question is: can we somehow tell Always On feature to ping not root of site but specific app url?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to have a look at azure webjob for your background tasks ?

Comment: Thomas, thanks for suggestion, we will consider this as last resort, because we do not want to be strongly tied to Azure. We want to be able migrate from Azure to on premises at any time.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't used it yet but you probably looking for this feature: [Application Initialization to warm up specific pages when app pool starts](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/6972595-application-initialization-to-warm-up-specific-pag).

This should allow you to specify multiple pages.

Comment: Martin, thanks.
But this is not exactly what I'm looking for: I need to prevent App Pool from stopping - my application must be active (in memory) 24/7 in order to process background jobs by schedule.

Comment: Can't you combine it with the always on feature and a redirect rule that invokes the warmup?

Comment: It is good idea.
Something like this?

    <rule name="Redirect AlwaysOn requests from root to custom url" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^$"/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^AlwaysOn$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://mycustomdomain.com/app1/ping" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>